# How to restrict a text input only to accept letter M and F using HTML 5(preferably) or javascript(no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a textbox, and i do not want to use dropdown for some reasons

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="gender" value="M" 
              size="32" />
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect place for a pair of radio buttons rather than a text input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp), check this [demo](http://html5pattern.com/Make_Your_Own?pattern_new=M#n=Name%E2%80%A6&p=M%7CF&d=Description%E2%80%A6&s=Source%E2%80%A6&pc[0]=%2B&nc[0]=-)

```
 <input type="text" required="required" name="gender" value="M" pattern="M|F" size="32" title="only letter M or F is allowed" />
```

Comment: Works great, What about changing the 'please match the requested format' notification to 'only letter M or F is allowed'

Comment: @KrushioVida check the title attribute in the updated answer

Comment: I have seen it  title="Only letter M or F is allowed"

Answer (score 1):

hope this will usefull for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f(v)
    {
        if(v=='F' || v=='M' || v=='f' || v=='m')
        {
            document.getElementById("t").value=v;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("t").value="";   
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="f(this.value)" id="t" required="required" name="gender" value="M" size="32" />
```